Are Fregian abstract objects Kantian noumena?
Kant defines noumena like this:

if, however, I suppose that there be things that are merely objects of the understanding and that, nevertheless, can be given to an intuition, although not to sensible intuition (as coram intuiti intellectuali), then such things would be called noumena (intelligibilia). (A249)

(copied from SEP).
Kant considers mathematical objects to be objects, but he considers them to be cognized at least in part through sensibility. He doesn't seem to make Frege's ontological distinction between objects connected to the senses in some way (such as physical objects and geometrical objects) and objects that are not, such as numbers. Frege wants to prove that numbers can be known through pure logic (that is, without an intuition), but this is problematic, and an alternative view is that numbers are known through an entirely non-sensible intuition. Kant doesn't have a form of intuition that would work for this--at least not a form of intuition available to mortals, but it seems like a fairly straightforward extension to add a form of intuition connected to the understanding instead of to sensibility. And in this case, it seems to me that those abstract objects would be noumena.

No. Kant did construe mathematical objects as objects and not mere concepts in CPR. They are attached to pure intuitions of productive imagination. He specifically emphasized that one cannot prove theorems about them otherwise in his examples with isosceles triangle and 7+5=12. That is how mathematics is "synthetic a priori". Frege's abstract objects, on the other hand, do not need intuitions, at least, not in arithmetic (he hesitated on geometry). But mathematical objects are the closest thing we have to noumena as cognized by "intellectual intuition" of their creator denied to us in CJ.

@david, what do you mean by "you need a form of intuition to cognize( become aware of) their representation?"

@leepappas, I mean that Kant believed mortals can only be aware of an object through an intuition that represents the object under the categories, so if this were true for abstract objects, you would need a form of intuition that is not connected to sensibility--or so I thought, but Conifold seems to disagree.

@Conifold, yes, Frege thought we could become aware of objects through pure logic, but I was applying Kantian epistemology to Fregean ontology. So, if Kant thinks mathematical objects are objects, doesn't he also say that the only way to become aware of an object is by intuition, and that all intuition is connected to sensibility? It seems like a contradiction.

Pure intuitions are sensibility. In fact, sensibility that operates in empirical cognition is the same one that produces pure intuitions in its a priori exercise, and makes them congruent to the categories of the understanding through schemata. That is Kant's explanation of why pure mathematics and a priori parts of physics are applicable to empirical experience.

@Conifold, so according to Kant, numbers are known through sensibility?

Through pure sensibility and understanding, like everything else. "Concepts without intuitions are empty, intuitions without concepts are blind".

@Conifold, I've edited the second paragraph in response to your comments.

You may be interested in CJ §77 where Kant discusses the kind of Understanding it would take to cognize noumena. It does not seem that attaching non-sensible intuition to our "discursive" understanding would suffice, it needs to be upended:"Our Understanding has this peculiarity... that in cognition by it the particular is not determined by the universal and cannot therefore be derived from it... We can however think an Understanding which proceeds... from the intuition of a whole as such to the particular."

He then suggests that such intellectus archetypus cognizes through production of the wholes without assembling them from parts. Cognition of the noumena is the ability "to represent to itself such a unity in the connexion of the manifold... the Idea of the unity being at the same time its producing cause." In other words, non-sensible intuition is only a small part of what is needed, the bigger part is bringing wholes into being. No finite Reason like ours in quality, however much it may surpass it in degree, can hope to understand the production of even a blade of grass..."

@Conifold, yes, I'm aware of that passage, and one of the things I had in mind is that although Kant's argument is reasonable with respect to material objects, it is not persuasive with respect to abstract objects, where, for example, the concept of a number does in fact entail pretty much everything about the number that is not related to other sorts of entities (for example, it doesn't tell you who is thinking about the number). In a sense, the concept of the number two does in fact bring the number two into being.

I am sympathetic. Intuiting the outputs of productive imagination does seem like the closest thing to what intuitive intellect is supposed to do with noumena as its own creations. It does not even matter much whether the intuition is sensible or not. However, we do not intuit them as wholes complete with "connections of parts". We do not 'see' whether 1679 is prime or composite, abundant or deficient, we only arrive at that piecemeal, discursively, if at all. Our concept of 1679 only entails an object, it does not produce it as intuited. We do not cognize them as noumena, only as "forms".

According to Kant

if, however, I suppose that there be things that are merely objects of the understanding and that, nevertheless, can be given to an intuition, although not to sensible intuition (as coram intuiti intellectuali), then such things would be called noumena (intelligibilia). (A249)

Paraphrasing

If, however, I suppose that there be things that are merely objects of the understanding and that, nevertheless, can be [given?] to an immediate understanding without evident  conscious thought or rational inference, although not to sensible intuition (as before looked at known), then such things would be called noumena.

Now Kant says the understanding has no concepts available to it other than the 12 categories.  The number one, would thus be an object of the category Unity.  Thus, the number one would be a noumenon.  Understanding of the number one is obtained in utero, before the mind is flooded with sensory data, by the fetal mind knowing the self is one thing.  The understanding of god as Kant imagined, is obtained according to Kant by intellectual intuition, an ability foreign to mortals.  Intellectual intuition is Kant's term for non-sensible intuition.  Thus Kant is wrong that only god has intellectual intuition, since any fetus understands the number one.
Now to Frege.
From the SEP
Frege's abstract/concrete division is made through use of the statement
A thing is abstract if and only if it's non-mental and non-sensible.
The problem is, electrons, protons, etc. are abstract, according to Frege's definition of abstract objects.
So the answer to your question is at an impasse.
Now to the OP.

Kant considers mathematical objects to be objects, but he considers them to be cognized at least in part through sensibility. He doesn't seem to make Frege's ontological distinction between objects connected to the senses in some way (such as physical objects and geometrical objects) and objects that are not, such as numbers. Frege wants to prove that numbers can be known through pure logic (that is, without an intuition), but this is problematic, and an alternative view is that numbers are known through an entirely non-sensible intuition. Kant doesn't have a form of intuition that would work for this--at least not a form of intuition available to mortals, but it seems like a fairly straightforward extension to add a form of intuition connected to the understanding instead of to sensibility. And in this case, it seems to me that those abstract objects would be noumena.


I don't see how Kant sees numbers as cognized at least in part by sensible intuition.  The natural numbers are built up from the number one, and the operation of addition.  Thus they, even by Kantian confusion, are noumena.

Kant might not explicitly distinguish between objects connected to the senses in some way, and those that are not e.g. numbers, but surely he was aware of the division.

Frege wanted to prove that numbers can be known through pure logic, because of his set theoretic definition of the number one.  He wanted to bypass intuition, and this is indeed problematic since a fetus understands the number one by intuition.  Kant does have a form of intuition that would work for this, intellectual intuition, but sadly Kant saw this as a non-mortal ability.


Now OP clearly states their position.

it seems like a fairly straightforward extension to add a form of intuition connected to the understanding instead of to sensibility. And in this case, it seems to me that those abstract objects would be noumena.

Indeed, had Kant viewed his intellectual intuition as a mortal ability, connected to the understanding of numbers, it appears to me also that numbers as noumena would be abstract objects.  And generalizing this, we could say Kantian noumena are Fregian abstract objects.
Nous is the ancient Greek word for mind, so if Kant meant by the term noumena mind-things, your conclusion is further supported.
The main problem in equating the two seems to be, Frege's definition of abstract objects is unclear.
